# Java Scripting for web page front end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Sorry New to webpage building. I'm building a front end to a build server, to make it easy for people to create csv's to build vm's. What I want to do is create the first page with 2 drop down menu's. The first pulls from a txt file with the Vcenters in it.

```
Vcenters.txt
-----------------------------------
test1.com
test2.com
```

Once lets say they pick test1.com it will then populate the second menu with the Datacenters

```
test1.com.txt
---------------------------------------------------------------
vcenter1
vcenter2
```

Once thats picked I need it to go to the right form page

```
./test1.com/vcenter1/form.html
```

I'm racking my brain trying to figure this out, any help would be greatly appreciated. I have the form created and the parsing of the json file from all the vcenters. This is the last piece.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Look for cascading dropdowns

Comment: ajax is what you want here

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks for your help pointing me in the right direction.

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#_Vcenter").change(function () {
$("#_Dcenter").load("info/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
});
});
function sndForm() {
var vcenter = document.getElementById("_Vcenter").value;
var dcenter = document.getElementById("_Dcenter").value;

location.href = './' + vcenter + "/data/" + dcenter + '/index.html';
return false;
}
</script>
```